# Installing Rosetta-dependent software on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I've got some old programs that I still need to dip in to from time to time, but they are old Rosetta-dependent software.

Is there a 3rd party install I can do to make my Lion machine be able to run them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

- If your Mac came pre-installed with Snow Leopard or earlier, you can simply **downgrade your Mac using the installation media**. Note that you cannot downgrade a Mac that came with Lion or newer.
- Install an older version of OS X in a virtual machine, using VMWare, VirtualBox, or Parallels. You may need a software license.
- Obvious, but added for completeness. **Check if the software in question has an update**. [Roaring Apps](http://roaringapps.com) may be able to help you out.

One thing you can not do is simply install Rosetta on your Lion machine. It relies on some old code and kernel extensions which simply do not exist in Lion.

Comment: sorry ignore that last comment